# Usage of Callipygian / Callipygous

Tags: word-usage

I am not at all familiar with this word. Oxford dictionary defines *Callipygian* as

> **adjective** (*rare*) having well-shaped buttocks.
>
> DERIVATIVES callipygous | ˌkalɪˈpɪdʒəs, ˌkalɪˈpʌɪdʒəs | adjective

I came across it in the following context:

> Search on YouTube for "female long jumpers"...notice anything
> consistent about the thumbnails? Why do the cameramen at these sports
> events seem so adroit at focusing on the most callipygian of the
> ladies?

The usage of the word *callipygian* in the above sentence somehow doesn't feel correct. Is it because *callipygian* is used rather than *callipygous*, or is the sentence grammatically incorrect in either case?

Comment: The adjective is described as 'rare' for a reason - it's a high-sounding expression which is not normally used in everyday speech. The writer is using it in a joking way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Callipygian* and *callipygous* have virtually the same definition and are interchangeable.

> **callipygian**, *adj.*
>
> Designating a person who has well-shaped or finely developed buttocks;
> of or relating to such a person. Also: of or relating to the buttocks.
>
> **callipygous**, *adj.*
>  <sub>Compare earlier CALLIPYGIAN *adj.*</sub>
>
> Designating a person who has well-shaped or finely developed buttocks;
> of or relating to such a person; = CALLIPYGIAN *adj.*
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Here’s an example usage offered by the *OED*:

> <sub>2011   *New Yorker* 28 Mar. 60/3   The famously
> callipygian television personality Kim Kardashian makes frequent
> requests for free Spanx.</sub>

You can swap in — for the sake of adjectival illustration — *fine-butted* wherever you see either to see that the usage is correct. For example:

> *The famously fine-butted television personality Kim Kardashian makes frequent requests for free Spanx.*
>
> *Why do the cameramen at these sports events seem so adroit at focusing on the most fine-butted of the ladies?*

To know before you go . . .

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that [*callipygian* is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=callipygian%2Ccallipygous&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccallipygian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccallipygous%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccallipygian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccallipygous%3B%2Cc0).

If you need an adverb, the *OED* lists the derivative adverb *callipygously*. *Callipygianously* is not in use.

*Callipygous* is pronounced cal-uh-PIE-gus (ˌkæləˈpaɪɡəs), with a hard *g* and a long-*i* *y*. *Callipygian* has a soft *g* and a short-*i* *y* (ˌkæləˈpɪdʒiən). [(Hear the pronunciations.)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/callipygous)